# bootstrap cards do not line up horizontally in react

Tags: reactjs, alignment, react-bootstrap, card

I have a problem with bootstrap cards, when I insert the code they just line up vertically, one below the other,
I do it by mapping a response

[image]

```
return (

        
            <div className="container">
                {array.map(name => (
                    < div class="card-columns ">
                        <div class='col'>
                            <div class="card ">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src=name.img" alt="Card image cap" />
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title"> name.title </h5>
                                    <p class="card-text"> name.description</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div >
        }
```

any way to align it so that it is next to each other?

Comment: Have you tried giving your wrapper a display flex and flex-direction row?

Comment: Based on your code, it looks like you are mapping everything into a col instead of a row, right? I think Bootstrap differentiate between rows and columns with the class?

Comment: Also about your className. `card-title` and `card-text` is Bootstrap class and always be stack vertically.

Answer (score 1):

please do it in this order

```
      return (
      <div className="container">
        <div class="row">
          {array.map((name) => (
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="card ">
                <img class="card-img-top" src={name.img} alt="Card image cap" />
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title"> {name.title} </h5>
                  <p class="card-text"> {name.description}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      }
```

Comment: Yeap the outer div with class 'row' is basically the solution.